# Installed MySQL Server on Mac OSX 10.7.5, receiving a 1045 (28000) error when trying to access MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, macos

Relatively new to SQL, I am reaching out for any advice on how to access MySQL via the Terminal shell on a MAC OSX 10.7.5 system. I have gotten this far detailed in the script below, and followed all installation guides on the web, as well as doing a fair amount of troubleshooting to try and move past the "ACCESS DENIED to "KV88@localhost, PASWORD: NO".

Can anyone provide insight on to why I can't input regular MySQL syntax and access the server, I believe I am still stuck in the BASH script environment.

SCRIPT:

ClickAways-MacBook:~ KV88$ sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start

Starting MySQL database server

ClickAways-MacBook:~ KV88$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'KV88'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

ClickAways-MacBook:~ KV88$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

During the installation you had to be asked about root password. So, you can access the server like this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and input your password. Then give access to your user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVLIEGES ON *.* TO 'KV88'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "<password>";
```

if you want for a user to be able to do (almost) everything, or create a database under root and give access to this database:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
GRANT ALL PRIVLIEGES ON mydb.* TO 'KV88'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Then exit mysql and enter as a user:

```
mysql -u KV88 -p
```

or

```
mysql -u KV88 -p mydb
```

Comment: Thank you only thing is as I was installing the MySQL Server application on to my Mac I was never prompted or asked regarding a root password. Unless I skipped over it somehow, I never inputted any password or was asked to. Is there any way to go around this, or should I uninstall and re-install?

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords